# Unable to load fast.com in webview

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-websettings

I want to create a simple app with a few useful webview links but fast.com will not load

```
webView.loadUrl("https://fast.com");
```

I've tried most webSettings but nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the one setting you might be missing is this

```
websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Narendra_Nath you are correct, it works fine with `websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I also used to develop apps and I have also faced same problem. And I found that making `webview` wrap_content also make these problems so make `webview` size `match_parent`. And put it on a linear layout or on other layout to make of your size.
And also enable on your java file.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```